# Spawning (and killing) Uvicorn/FastAPI backend from Electron (or Node.js)

Tags: python, node.js, electron, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm building a Python backend for an Electron app using FastAPI (and Uvicorn). I develop on both macOS and Windows, so I'm looking for a cross-platform solution to the following question.

**How can I spawn and gracefully kill a python Uvicorn server from Node.js (specifically the `electron.js` script of my Electron app)?**

The only way I've been able to launch the server is with `exec` instead of `spawn`. So this works:

```js
const { spawn, exec, execFile } = require("child_process");

function launchPython() {
  pythonProcess = exec(
    "C:\\Users\\user2\\miniconda3\\envs\\myenv\\python.exe .\\py_src\\main.py"
  );
  console.log("Python process started in dev mode")
  return pythonProcess;
}
```

But this does not:

```js
function launchPython() {
  pythonProcess = spawn(
    "C:\\Users\\user2\\miniconda3\\envs\\myenv\\python.exe .\\py_src\\main.py"
  );
  console.log("Python process started in dev mode")
  return pythonProcess;
}
```

`.\py_src\main.py` looks like this:

```py
import uvicorn


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(
        "app.api:app", 
        host="0.0.0.0", 
        port=8000, 
        reload=True
        )
```

Also, upon exiting the Electron app, the Uvicorn server is not killed. The "exit" code in my main `electron.js` file is as follows:

```js
app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    pythonProcess.kill();
    app.quit();
    return
  }
});
```

So two main questions:

1. Why doesn't `spawn` work to run the python Uvicorn server (`py_src\main.py`)? **NOTE**: I'm using a specific python version from a Miniconda environment. Could that be the cause?
2. How can I shutdown the Uvicorn server programmatically when the Electron app exits (because killing the python process that I opened with `exec` doesn't seem to work)?

Eventually I'm going to use Pyinstaller to build an executable for the FastAPI backend, and launch it with `child_process.execFile`, which is why I need a programmatic way to shutdown the Uvicorn server (e.g. with a "quit" or "shutdown" call to the API)

Comment: Any solutions for this?